# Animate frame series with hyperlinks

Tags: minipage, links, animations, shortcut

I would like to show 20 (or more) separate frames of an animation and let the user "plays" the frames to create the animation illusion. For each cases I provide a MWE taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/526611/animation-a-plan-cutting-a-surface).

By creating a link to the next image for each image of a frame series, I am able to create a animation illusion by rapidly clicking on each image.
However, clicking rapidly is rather painful and can create unwanted shortcuts depending a the pdf viewer used by the user.

```latex
% ---------------------------- Hyperlink animation --------------------------- %
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {-4.5,-4,...,4.5}{ 
        \hypertarget{link\the\numexpr\j-1\relax}{}
        \hyperlink{link\j}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[grid=major,view={20}{40},z buffer=sort, data cs=polar]
                \addplot3 [surf, domain=0:360, domain y=5-\i:10,samples=30, samples y=1+\j]
                {-y+5};
                \addplot3 [data cs=cart,surf,domain=-10:10,samples=2, opacity=0.5,point
                meta=0]
                {\i};
                \addplot3 [domain=0:360, samples y=0, samples=30, thick, z buffer=auto]
                (x,5.1-\i,\i);
                \addplot3 [surf,domain=0:360, domain y=0:5-\i,samples=30, samples y=21-\j]
                {-y+5};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}} 
\end{document}
```

By using the standalone class, I am able to create small pages with individual figure that I can add to my main document later. With this method, you can easily view animation by changing to the next page, which is easy holding the "right-arrow" key.
However, this method creates 20 pages (or more) that are irrelevant to count.

```latex
% --------------------------- Multi-page animation --------------------------- %
\documentclass[multi=my,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
    \foreach \i [count=\j] in {-4.5,-4,...,4.5}{ 
        \begin{my}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{axis}[grid=major,view={20}{40},z buffer=sort, data cs=polar]
                    \addplot3 [surf, domain=0:360, domain y=5-\i:10,samples=30, samples y=1+\j]
                    {-y+5};
                    \addplot3 [data cs=cart,surf,domain=-10:10,samples=2, opacity=0.5,point
                    meta=0]
                    {\i};
                    \addplot3 [domain=0:360, samples y=0, samples=30, thick, z buffer=auto]
                    (x,5.1-\i,\i);
                    \addplot3 [surf,domain=0:360, domain y=0:5-\i,samples=30, samples y=21-\j]
                    {-y+5};
                \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{my}} 
\end{document}
```

To addess my problems :

- Is there a way to create hyperlinks with a built in shortcut that user can use to jump to the next image ? This way I add all my images one 1 or 2 pages jumping to the next one with a keyboard shortcut.
- Or is there a way to not count a group of pages, neither by the latex document itself and by the pdf viewer, but still allowing the pdf viewer to use the next page shortcut to view the animation ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: With the `animate` package you can compile your multipage PDF image sequence into an animation living inside a single PDF page. Clicking the play-button once will start animation playback, but stepping frame-wise is possible too.